# Jquery - Maximum call stack on animation callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback

> This is my last shot at fixing this project before I throw it in the
>   toilet. So basically its a slider that pulls data from images within a
>   slide-data container. It styles it with css classes when it applies it
>   to a div. My question is why am I getting "maximum call stack size
>   exceeded" when I run this? I'm using animation callbacks so really
>   there should be no issue. Either way I am exiting the function with
>   return aswell. I'm not sure whats going on.
>
> Please ignore global vars and commented sections as I have been trying
>   many solutions to this issue.

Completed slider script for anyone that cares.

*JS (requires jQuery & jQuery UI Effects):*

```
var dt=5000; //set this to determine slide delay time

function transitionSlides(){c++;if(c<=i){$(".slide-holder").toggle("slide",{direction:"right"},"fast");return changeBackground()}else{c=0;return transitionSlides()}}function changeBackground(){var e=c.toString();var t=$("#slide"+e).attr("title");var n=$("#slide"+e).attr("src");$(".slide-holder").css("background","url("+n+") no-repeat").html(t).delay(dt).toggle("slide",{direction:"left"},"fast",transitionSlides)}var c=0;var i=new Number;$(document).ready(function(e){i=$(".slide-data").children("img").length;transitionSlides()})
```

CSS:

```
.slide-holder {
    font-family: /* slide font */
        font-size:40px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    text-shadow:2px 2px 3px #000;
}
.slide-data, .slides {
    display:none;
}
.slide-frame, .slide-holder { /* slide-frame keeps page from jarring up and down when slide-holder exits */
    height:325px;
    width:800px;
}
```

HTML Markup Example:

```
<div class="slide-frame">
<div class="slide-holder"></div>
<div class="slide-data">
<img src="images/slides/slide1.png" class="slides" id="slide1" width="800" height="325" alt="empowering startups" title="slide text one" />
<img src="images/slides/slide2.png" class="slides" id="slide2" width="800" height="325" title="This is a test" />
<img src="images/slides/slide3.png" class="slides" id="slide3" width="800" height="325" title="This is also a test" />
<img src="images/slides/slide4.png" class="slides" id="slide4" width="800" height="325" title="Testing the last one too." />
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `transitionSlides` instead of passing it as a callback.  Remove the `()`.

```
$(".slide-holder").delay(4000).toggle("slide", { direction: "left"}, "fast", transitionSlides)
```

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(e) {
    transitionSlides();
    //var timer = $.timer(transitionSlides, 5000);
    //timer.play();
});

function transitionSlides () {
 i = $(".slide-data").children("img").length;
 console.log("Children: " + i);
    c++;
    cx = c.toString();
    if(c <= i) {
       // if(fr = false) {
        $(".slide-holder").toggle("slide", { direction: "right"}, "fast");
  return changeBackground();
  //$("#header").append(msg);
    } else {
        c = 0;
        return transitionSlides();
    }
}`

Console prints "Children: 4".

Comment: c is basically the selector. It is incremented each time to select the next slide to animate. When it is above the number of slides, it is reset to 0 and incremented again so it can run the animation correctly. If I look at the call stack log it reads, "transitionSlides, changeBackground, transitionSlides, changeBackground, transitionSlides, changeBackground, transitionSlides, changeBackground, transitionSlides, transitionSlides"